# Is it possible from VCL to invoke a module function after a request has been processed?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
sub vcl_after_response_is_sent {
  mymod.f(req, resp);
}
```

But I don't see any [builtin subroutine](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html#client-side) that could let you do this. Is there any other way it might be accomplished?

Comment: Why [vcl_fini](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html#vcl-fini) wouldn't be up for the task?

Comment: Isn't that only called after all requests are processed? I want something invoked for each request, not long after it's been processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [PRIV_TASK](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod.html#private-pointers) with a free function.

In the module's VCC declare the function as follows:

```
$Function VOID f(PRIV_TASK)
```

Use something like the following for the function's definition:

```
void finish_request(void*) {
}

VCL_VOID vmod_trace_request(VRT_CTX, struct vmod_priv* priv_task) {
  priv_task->priv = /* Some non-null value */
  priv_task->free = finish_request;
}
```

If `f` is then called from `vcl_recv`

```
sub vcl_recv {
  mymod.f();
}
```

`finish_request` will be invoked when varnish is done with the request.